# how can I avoid escape character \" when I use ‘Op.notLike ’ in function of "findAll " in eggjs model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code

```js
    async getHisDataByTime(startTime, endTime, ids) {
        console.log("getHisDataByTime >>", startTime, endTime, ids)
        const Op = this.ctx.app.Sequelize.Op;
        const dataHis = await this.ctx.model.Datahis.findAll({
          where: {
            device_id: { [Op.in]: ids },
            datetime: {
              [Op.gte]: startTime,
              [Op.lte]: endTime
            },
            data:{
              [Op.notLike]: '%valid%',
            }
          },
          //group:['device_id'],
          order: [['datetime']],
          attributes: ['device_id', 'datetime', 'data']
        });
    
        return dataHis;
      }
```

which generates this sql command:

```
SELECT `device_id`, `datetime`, `data` FROM `data_his` AS `datahis` 
WHERE `datahis`.`device_id` IN ('2019083107100024', '2020010303100002') 
  AND (`datahis`.`datetime` >= '2019-09-23 00:00:00' 
  AND `datahis`.`datetime` <= '2019-09-24 23:00:00') 
  AND `datahis`.`data` NOT LIKE '\"%valid%\"' 
ORDER BY `datahis`.`datetime`;
```

I expected `'%valid%'`，but actually got `'\"%valid%\"'`. The escaped character `\"` appears automatically，and the mysql command performs as follows:

[image]

so, `Op.notLike` does not work at all in this case.

after I remove the escape character `\"` and execute it in Navicat, the result is just what I want：
[image]

but how can I avoid  escape character `\"` in "findAll" to fix this out? I've compared my code with the official example below, however, useless.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

[image]

Comment: I suspect `**'%valid%'**`  is actually `'%valid%'` in your code, and you only tried to emphasize it here?

Comment: Can you include the exact unedited code? My guess is that it's some kind of variable replacement.

Comment: Yes, thanks, derpirscher. I have revised my post@derpirscher

Comment: hey, doublesharp,I've rearranged the code in the post, it's unmodified now. '%valid%' just a string, not a variable.  Considering the situation of sensitive words, I changed '%valid%' to '%test%' or other,however,the escape characters appear the same way。@doublesharp

Answer (score 0):

So far, it is not known what caused the escape character,but there are two solutions here.

```
 1. public async query(sql: string, options: object): Promise using
 2. JSON_CONTAINS_PATH to check the key of data
```

code for solution 2:

```
async getHisDataByTime(startTime, endTime, ids) {
        console.log("getHisDataByTime >>", startTime, endTime, ids)
        const { Op } = this.app.Sequelize;
        let validFn =  this.app.Sequelize.fn("JSON_CONTAINS_PATH", this.app.Sequelize.col("data"), 'one', '$.valid');
        const dataHis = await this.ctx.model.Datahis.findAll({
          where: {
            [Op.and]: [
              { device_id: { [Op.in]: ids } },
              {
                datetime: {
                  [Op.gte]: startTime,
                  [Op.lte]: endTime
                }
              },
              this.app.Sequelize.where(validFn, 0)
            ]
          },
          //group:['device_id'],
          order: [['datetime']],
          attributes: ['device_id', 'datetime', 'data']
        });
    
        return dataHis;
      }
```